# Mostrar el rol de usuario dependiendo del tipo de documento, y asignar rol con select dependiente

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

Tengo un select dependiente

```
/*Inicio obtenemos los datos del primer select*/
$sql = "select documento , tipo_usuario from tblusuario";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($conexion);
/* Fin Inicio obtenemos los datos del primer select*/

    <select id="tblusuario">
      <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
      <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //llenar las opciones del primer select ?>
                             <option value="<?=$op['documento']?>"> <?=$op['documento']?> </option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>

    <br/><br/>
    <label>perfil</label>
    <select id="tbltipousuario" name="tipousuario" disabled="">
      <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
    <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //llenar las opciones del primer select ?>
                                                             <option value="<?=$op['id']?>"> <?=$op['nombre']?> </option>

                            <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```

El codigo ajax es este

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var tbltipousuario = $('#tbltipousuario');

        //Ejecutar accion al cambiar de opcion en el select de las bandas
        $('#tblusuario').change(function(){
          var usuario_doc= $(this).val(); //obtener el id seleccionado

          if(usuario_doc !== ''){ //verificar haber seleccionado una opcion valida

            /*Inicio de llamada ajax*/
            $.ajax({
              data: { usuario_doc : usuario_doc }, //variables o parametros a enviar, formato => nombre_de_variable:contenido
              dataType: 'html', //tipo de datos que esperamos de regreso
              type: 'POST', //mandar variables como post o get
              url: 'traer_rol.php' //url que recibe las variables
            }).done(function(data){ //metodo que se ejecuta cuando ajax ha completado su ejecucion
  if(data != '') {
    tbltipousuario.html(data); //establecemos el contenido html de discos con la informacion que regresa ajax
  }
  tbltipousuario.prop('disabled', false); //habilitar el select
            });
            /*fin de llamada ajax*/

          }else{ //en caso de seleccionar una opcion no valida
            tbltipousuario.val(''); //seleccionar la opcion "- Seleccione -", osea como reiniciar la opcion del select
            tbltipousuario.val('');
            tbltipousuario.prop('disabled', true); //deshabilitar el select
          }
        });


        //mostrar una leyenda con el disco seleccionado
        $('#tbltipousuario').change(function(){
          $('#tbltipousuario_sel').html($(this).val() + ' - ' + $('#tbltipousuario option:selected').text());
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Explicaré el procedimiento :

Cuando en el primer select(documento)  eligo una opción, el segundo select(rol/perfil) se deshabilita y suelta dos resultados:

1.
si el documento no tiene un rol/perfil , solo la opcion vacia

```
      <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
```

2. 

si el documento tiene un rol me muestra la opcion anterior mas el rol, osea me muestra dos opciones la opción por defect, y el dato que quiero traer

lo que quiero es que cuando el documento tenga un rol, no me muestre la opcion -seleccione- por defecto , quiero que solo me muestre el rol, solo un option.
También quiero que cuando el documento no tenga rol, me muestre la opcion -seleccione- y ademas me muestre todos los roles que existen, para que el usuario pueda elegir uno...

-------------------------MODIFICACIÓN------------------------------

configure el la funcion data, para verificar si trae algo , porfavor revisen el codigo arriba otravez.
Me pidieron que mostrará la variable data por consola, no muestra nada con el este codigo, pero seguramente es porque no la he pasado por consola, me pueden decir como debo hacerlo porfavor?

Este es el archivo traer_rol.php que es al que se redirecciona en el ajax

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/conexion.php'; //libreria de conexion a la base

$usuario_doc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario_doc'); //obtenemos el parametro que viene de ajax

if ($usuario_doc != '') { //verificamos nuevamente que sea una opcion valida

    if (!$conexion) {
        die("<br/>Sin conexión.");

    }

    /*Obtenemos los discos de la departamento seleccionada*/
    $sql = "SELECT
        tu.id, tu.nombre
    from
        tblusuario as u
            inner join
        tbltipousuario as tu ON u.tipo_usuario = tu.id
     where u.documento = " . $usuario_doc;

    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}

/* el combo dependiente */
?>

     </div>
     <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
    <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //creamos las opciones a partir de los datos obtenidos ?>
                                        <option value="<?=$op['id']?>"><?=$op['nombre']?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que tienes en `traer_rol.php` y lo que aparece en la consola con `console.log(data);` dentro del método `done()`

Answer (score 0):

Porque no chequeas si la variable `data` trae informacion?  Algo asi:

```
$.ajax({
  data: { usuario_doc : usuario_doc }, //variables o parametros a enviar, formato => nombre_de_variable:contenido
  dataType: 'html', //tipo de datos que esperamos de regreso
  type: 'POST', //mandar variables como post o get
  url: 'traer_rol.php' //url que recibe las variables
}).done(function(data){ //metodo que se ejecuta cuando ajax ha completado su ejecucion
  if(data != '') {
    tbltipousuario.html(data); //establecemos el contenido html de discos con la informacion que regresa ajax
  }
  tbltipousuario.prop('disabled', false); //habilitar el select
});
```

Comment: Lo intenté, sin embargo el resultado es el mismo